# Lazy loading in HorizontalScrollView to prevent Out of Memory issue

Tags: android, lazy-loading, horizontalscrollview, out-of-memory

I want to add lazy loading feature to HorizontalScrollView, It has 
linearlayout as a child and i am addding to linearlayout, 
I am interested in listening to the event when the child view is out 
of the visibility area,  I see in linearlayout implementation it does 
not call either dispatchViewVisibility or onDraw on child view , why i 
want that because bitmap attached to the child view can be recycled 
and create bitmap again when child view is visible (well that is a 
separate part ,How can i create that bitmap very fast, I am planning 
to use opengl for that) but the question is how can make such custom 
view. 
I can not use gallery view because it does not solve my purpose 
I saw that viewgroup has feature of dispatchingViewVisibility and 
dispatchOnDraw but not sure how to use that with 
HorizontalScrollView.? 
All i am doing to prevent Out of Memory issue 
Any suggestion and help would be appreciated 
thanks

Comment: go here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview and try that but for your list not dificult have fun

Comment: @subspider I want to have horizontal layout not the listview thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `HorizontalScrollView`. Instead, use the `ViewPager` component that was added to the Android Compatibility Library, as it is designed for this sort of scenario. [Here is a blog post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html) that explains a bit more.

Comment: I tried ViewPager it is cool , but its require one page per pic which i dont want earlier we had horizontal scroll view with atleast 4-5 images in the area of visibility. Any suggestion thanks
**